# Is Azure ServiceBus MessageSender class safe to run as a singleton in a long-lived process?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azureservicebus

I have a long-running process that wakes up, performs some task, and may or may not need to publish a message via `MessageSender` to the Azure service bus. If I can make the `MessageSender` a singleton, that slightly simplifies my code, so I'd like to if it is viable.

To clarify, I expect that this process may go for very long periods of time (hours at least, potentially days) without sending any messages to the service bus.

Super-simplified example:

```cs
public async Task WorkLoop(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var result = DoWork();
        if (result.shouldPublish)
        {
            var message = buildMessage(result);
            await _messageSender.SendAsync(message);
        }
        await Task.Delay(sleepDuration, token);
    }
}
```

Are there any consequences to keeping a `MessageSender` instance alive for a long time (days at least, possibly weeks or months)?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients):

> It is recommended that you do not close messaging factories or queue,
>   topic, and subscription clients after you send a message, and then
>   re-create them when you send the next message. [...] You can safely
>   use these client objects for concurrent asynchronous operations and
>   from multiple threads.

Comment: That's helpful, but doesn't strictly answer the question. I'm looking for any potential *downsides* to using a single `MessageSender` instance for a long period of time. I've also added a clarification that I expect my process to have long gaps between sending messages, in case that matters.

Comment: @asgallant Did you go with singleton and did not face any issues? If there is quite a long gap between your sends, you might need to have Service Bus `Retry options` filled in while creating the SB _Client_ object.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I don't recall what I ended up doing. It was 4 years and a different job ago.